# REST Assured GET not working after making it generic

Tags: java, maven, testng, rest-assured

I am working on the GET request and I am trying to make it generic. I do not understand what is the mistake I have done here. Can any one help me out in tracing this out. The data from excel wil be generic in the GET request. The code can be found below.

Working on: **Java, RestAssured, TestNG, Maven**

This is my **Properties** file:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = http://website.com:8080/DBName;
```

This is my **Readproperties** file:

```
public class DemoTestcase {

String url;

@BeforeSuite
public void SetBrowser() {
    System.out.println("Before Suite....");
}

@BeforeMethod
public void load_property_file() throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("Configuration/config.properties");
    prop.load(input);
    System.out.println();
    url = prop.getProperty("RestAssured.baseURI");
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

My Code for **RestAssured API**: Here I am Trying to make it generic by using Data Provider and reading it from excel.

```
@Test(dataProviderClass = <packageName.className>.class, dataProvider = "urlParameters")

public void tc_008_using_BDD_keywords(final String readExcelData) {

    try {
        ValidatableResponse response = given()
                                       .when().get(url + "/{readExcelData}").then()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON);
        System.out.println(((ResponseBodyData) response).asString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("e.printStackTrace()");
    }
}
```

This is my **DataProvider**. I have written the logic for reading from the excel file and returning as Object [][] to @Test.

```
@DataProvider(name = "urlParameters")
public static Object[][] createUrlParameters() throws IOException, ParseException {

    <//Logic for reading Excel sheet containing 3 row and 1 column>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the "not working"? What is the current behavior? And what is the expected one?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not able to understand how to run then in the server. I have done the coding and since its not a web application how to configure to a server so that I can run in the post man and test it

Comment: What does exactly do not work?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you're using the variable wrong:

```
public void tc_008_using_BDD_keywords(final String readExcelData) {

    try {
        ValidatableResponse response = given()
                                       .when().get(url + "/{readExcelData}").then()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON);
        System.out.println(((ResponseBodyData) response).asString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("e.printStackTrace()");
    }
}
```

should be:

```
public void tc_008_using_BDD_keywords(final String readExcelData) {
    try {
        ValidatableResponse response = given()
                                       .when().get(url + "/" + readExcelData).then()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON);
        System.out.println(((ResponseBodyData) response).asString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("e.printStackTrace()");
    }}
```

`.get(url + "/{readExcelData}")` is reading `url/{readExcelData}` in Java. You're not using the actual variable.